# Date Not changing while using Data picker

Tags: android

I have a Two Textviews and Two Buttons in my Layout, I want to click the button to popup the data picker and choose the date finally all set to be particular textviews.

E.g

Button1 choose date set to Textview1
Button2 chhose date set to textview2

but the problem is first time working correctly but if i try 2nd time try to change the button1 but value set to Textview2.

first time only working   good.Plz guide me i am leaner step by step sorry for basic question.

```
// display current date
    public void setCurrentDateOnView() {

        tvDisplayDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDate);
        tvDisplayDate2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDate2);

        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // set current date into textview
        tvDisplayDate.setText(new StringBuilder()
                // Month is 0 based, just add 1
                .append(month + 1).append("-").append(day).append("-")
                .append(year).append(" "));

        tvDisplayDate2.setText(tvDisplayDate.getText().toString());
    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        btnChangeDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChangeDate);

        btnChangeDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);

            }

        });
        btnChangeDate2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChangeDate2);

        btnChangeDate2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID2);


            }

        });

    }

    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {

            case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
                System.out.println("onCreateDialog  : " + id);
                cur = DATE_DIALOG_ID;
                // set date picker as current date
                return new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener, year, month,
                        day);
            case DATE_DIALOG_ID2:
                cur = DATE_DIALOG_ID2;
                System.out.println("onCreateDialog2  : " + id);
                // set date picker as current date
                return new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener, year, month,
                        day);

        }
        return null;
    }


    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        // when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
                              int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {

            year = selectedYear;
            month = selectedMonth;
            day = selectedDay;

            if (cur == DATE_DIALOG_ID) {
                // set selected date into textview
                tvDisplayDate.setText(new StringBuilder().append(month + 1)
                        .append("-").append(day).append("-").append(year)
                        .append(" "));
                System.out.println("A");
                System.out.println(cur);
            }

            if (cur == DATE_DIALOG_ID2){
                tvDisplayDate2.setText(new StringBuilder().append(month + 1)
                        .append("-").append(day).append("-").append(year)
                        .append(" "));
                System.out.println("B");
                System.out.println(cur);
            }

        }
    };
```

> showDialog(); Deprecated message
>
> onCreateDialog Deprecated message
>
> showDialog() parameter does not change at the time of click

Comment: Create 2 datePickerListener for each DatePickerDialog and inside datePickerListener write code to set date on textview.

Comment: can you plz explain i can not get you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
      private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener1 = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    // when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
                          int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
        year = selectedYear;
        month = selectedMonth;
        day = selectedDay;
            // set selected date into textview
            tvDisplayDate.setText(new StringBuilder().append(month + 1)
                    .append("-").append(day).append("-").append(year)
                    .append(" "));

       }
};

  private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener2 = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    // when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
                          int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {

        year = selectedYear;
        month = selectedMonth;
        day = selectedDay;

            tvDisplayDate2.setText(new StringBuilder().append(month + 1)
                    .append("-").append(day).append("-").append(year)
                    .append(" "));
        }

    }
};


 protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {

        case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
            System.out.println("onCreateDialog  : " + id);
            cur = DATE_DIALOG_ID;
            // set date picker as current date
            return new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener1, year, month,
                    day);
        case DATE_DIALOG_ID2:
            cur = DATE_DIALOG_ID2;
            System.out.println("onCreateDialog2  : " + id);
            // set date picker as current date
            return new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener2, year, month,
                    day);

    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code for setting date using date picker

```
 btnChangeDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();


            int mYear = calender.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int mMonth = calender.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int mDay = calender.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            DatePickerDialog mDatePicker = new DatePickerDialog(SubscriptionActivity.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker datepicker, int selectedyear, int selectedmonth, int selectedday) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                /*      Your code   to get date and time    */
                    tvDisplayDate.setText((selectedmonth + 1) + "-"
                            + selectedday + "-" + selectedyear);

                }
            }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);



            mDatePicker.show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put break in switch case

```
break;
```

Final code is

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {

            case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
                System.out.println("onCreateDialog  : " + id);
                cur = DATE_DIALOG_ID;
                // set date picker as current date
                return new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener, year, month,
                        day);
                   break;
            case DATE_DIALOG_ID2:
                cur = DATE_DIALOG_ID2;
                System.out.println("onCreateDialog2  : " + id);
                // set date picker as current date
                return new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener, year, month,
                        day);
         break;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    btnChangeDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        // Get Current Date
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


        DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),
                new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                          int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                        tv_data.setText(dayOfMonth + "/" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "/" + year);
                    }
                }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
        datePickerDialog.show();

        }

    });
```